# How to set GLSurfaceView context in adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

**My adapter is a list of surface views**

---

**AdptImageEffects.java**

```
public class AdptImageEffects extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdptImageEffects.MyViewHolder> implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    private static ClickListener clickListener;
    private Activity activity;
    private FrgImageCompose fragment;
    private TextureRenderer mTexRenderer;


    public AdptImageEffects(Activity activity,
                            FrgImageCompose fragment) {

        this.fragment = fragment;
        this.activity = activity;
        mTexRenderer = new TextureRenderer();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl10, EGLConfig eglConfig) {
        Log.d("onSurfaceCreated","triggered first");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl10, int width, int height) {
        Log.d("onSurfaceChanged","triggered second");
        if (mTexRenderer != null) {
            mTexRenderer.updateViewSize(width, height);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl10) {
        Log.d("onDrawFrame","triggered");

    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener  {
        public GLSurfaceView mEffectView;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
            mEffectView = (GLSurfaceView) view.findViewById(R.id.mEffectView);
            mEffectView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
            mEffectView.setRenderer(this); //////////////////---------> Not able to Set this 
            mEffectView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
            initSurfaceView();
        }

        private void initSurfaceView() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            clickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), view);
        }
    }



    public void setOnItemClickListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
        AdptImageEffects.clickListener = clickListener;
    }

    public interface ClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position, View v);
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.row_adpt_image_effects, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

---

Not able to set `mEffectView.setRenderer(this);`

Comment: I got the same problem did u find this ?

Answer (score 0):

use `mEffectiveView.setRenderer(AdptImageEffects.this)`